# Как упаковать скрипты в 1 файл инсталяции

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть скрипты уже написанные 
auth.php
index.php
reports.php
robots.txt
config.php

Как их упаковать в 1 файл? 
И когда пользователь заливает его на хостинг, заходим там ввод пароля, когда вводим пароль и жмем ок, файлы распаковываются прямо на хостинге!
Как такое замутить?

Comment: использовать можно [php ziparchive](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ziparchive.php)  в частности вот пример добавления файлов http://php.net/manual/ru/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Это единственный вариант упаковки?

Comment: ещё есть исполняемый phar архив

Comment: @Naumov только на хосте (если он не принадлежит самим тем людям, кто заливает файл) возможность его исполнить вряд ли будет. Там файлы архивами заливаются.... Просто как дополнение к комменту

Comment: Нашёл от 1 писателя такой вот файл:http://rgho.st/8MCqg6Kr7   этот файл он заливает на хостинг,и от туда распаковываются при вводе пароля файлы